# All Jenkins jobs are getting triggered upon any changes in shared library

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, shared-libraries, jenkins-groovy

I have configured shared library for pipeline job, now hundreds of jobs are pointing to my single shared library. Upon making any changes in shared library files it triggers all the jenkins jobs associated with that shared library.

And i have noticed that every jenkins job is polling for shared library changes as well, is there way to restrict this ?

Below is my Jenkins jobs polling log.

```
Selected Git installation does not exist. Using Default
The recommended git tool is: NONE
using credential password-id
 > git --version # timeout=10
 > git --version # 'git version 1.8.3.1'
using GIT_ASKPASS to set credentials password-id
 > git ls-remote -h ssh://git@git:<my shared library repo>.git # timeout=10
Found 1 remote heads on ssh://git@git:<my shared library repo>.git
Using strategy: Default
[poll] Last Built Revision: Revision 12sjioiniibaerinklnaiaseioonbsjd (refs/remotes/origin/feature/branch_name)
The recommended git tool is: NONE
No credentials specified
 > git --version # timeout=10
 > git --version # 'git version 1.8.3.1'
 > git ls-remote -h ssh://git@git:<actual jenkins job repo>.git # timeout=10
Found 2668 remote heads on ssh://git@git:<actual jenkins job repo>.git
[poll] Latest remote head revision on refs/heads/feature/branch_name is: 12sjioiniibaerinklnaiaseioonbsjd - already built by 3
Done. Took 0.64 sec
No changes
```

I don't want all the hundred builds to be triggered when i make any changes in shared library, please let me know if there is way to achieve that.

Edit 1:

I have configured my shared library details in Manage jenkins > configure systems > Global Pipeline Libraries

So in configure systems will have the url of my shared library, default version details(branch/tag) and shared library name.

and in my pipeline Jobs am calling my shared library using shared library name like below.

shared lib example:

```
@Library('Maven_Build_Pipeline_test') _

pipeline {
    //agent { label "BLD-Slaves" }
    triggers { pollSCM('* * * * *') }
    stages {
        stage('Build') {
            steps {
                script{
                echo "######## Build is going on ########"
                sh 'ls -ltr'
                }   
            }
        }
    }
}
```